# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions exception in API 19

Tags: android

My Android app is running on Android `Lollipop` and `Marshmallow` version but when i run it on `API 19` it gives exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions exception
```

I am not using any firebase in may application. I search some related problem on Internet and apply in my app but right now i could not found any solution. Please help me

below is my top gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

below is my app gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dp.needdepartmentalstore"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 29
        versionName "5.16"
        multiDexEnabled true

        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "16c778cf-8ebc-47a8-9ba8-6815f0223a0e",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "253919422974"]


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.mikepenz:actionitembadge:3.1.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile project(':niceSpinner')
    compile files('libs/PGSDK_v1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/App42_ANDROID_SDK_3.8.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:1+') {
        exclude group: 'com.mcxiaoke.volley', module: 'library'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.18'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    //compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am facing a similar problem

Comment: @user3486992 I find the above solution. first remove 'compile com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0' from gradle file and use only those google play services api that is required in your application. [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) is link of all google service api. Its method is useful for me and app is running also on android API 19

Comment: i have included only the required play services api's. Still not working